# passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast....can any body help me

Tags: c, atoi

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    int a,b,ans[10000];
    char *c,*d,*e;
    int i = 0;
    c = (char*)(malloc(20 * sizeof(char)));
    d = (char*)(malloc(20 * sizeof(char)));
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(i < n){
            scanf("%d",&a);
            scanf("%d",&b);
            itoa(a,c,10);
            itoa(b,d,10);
            a = atoi(strrev(c)) + atoi(strrev(d));
            itoa(a,c,10);
            e = c;
            while(*e == '0')e++;
            ans[i] = atoi(strrev(e));
            i++;
            }
    i = 0;
    while(i < n){
            printf("%d\n",ans[i]);
            i++;
            }
}
```

Comment: There's a little 0s and 1s button in the Markdown editor for marking code.  Please use it on code snippets in the future.  Or just add 4 spaces of indent to each code line.

Comment: Thank you.I will use it from next time.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such function as `strrev` declared in your program. The compiler assumes that it's some unknown function that returns `int`. Hence the diagnostic message, since `atoi` expects a pointer, not an `int`.

What's `strrev`? And why are you attempting to call this function without declaring it first? C standard library has no such function, so including those standard headers that you have included already is not enough (unless you are assuming some extended implementation).

Comment: It is given as a library function at

http://www.warpspeed.com.au/cgi-bin/inf2html.cmd?..%5Chtml%5Cbook%5CToolkt40%5CXPG4REF.INF+275

Comment: It's not in MY string.h, though - gcc 4.4.1 on Ubuntu.  @somasekhar, what's your environment?

Comment: `strrev` is not a standard C function, so there's nothing surprising in in not being declared in a general case.

Comment: Thank You .I am using dev cpp on windows.This code is to be submitted on www.codechef.com,a practice problem.It do not have an option of dev c++.So,I have selected as gcc 4.3.2. But,it is working on dev cpp.SO I think gcc 4.3.2 do not have the function strrev().

Comment: Regarding strrev(). POSIXv6/SUSv3 doesn't have a mention of it. Neither C99 (N1124). Linux and FreeBSD do not have a man page for it. Conclusion: function isn't standard.

Answer (score 0):

Apart the problem of `strrev` which is not standard and can be easily implemented e.g.

```
char *strrev(char *s)
{
  size_t l = strlen(s), i;
  char *r = malloc(l + 1);
  if ( r != NULL ) {
    for(s += l-1, i=0; i < l; i++, s--) r[i] = *s;
    r[i] = '\0';
  }
  return r;
}
```

just to say (not-in-place reversion), you should prefer the use of `strtol` or `strtoul` instead of `atoi` and implement also `itoa` since afaik that is not standard too (you could use `sprintf` anyway if the base is 10).